# How to get the max value of a numeric input from jQuery function done on a class

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have an input that is being created by a PHP loop so i want to give each one a different max value from touch spin depending on a php value

blade.php code :

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach ($Ch as $chemical)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $chemical->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $chemical->categorie->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $chemical->model }}</td>
            <td>{{ $chemical->serial_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $chemical->unit_price }} {{ $chemical->contract->currency->symbol }}</td>
            <td>{{ $chemical->weight }}</td>
            <td>
                @php
                    $sum = 0;
                    foreach ($chemical->recieved_quantity as $rq) {
                        $sum += $rq->quantity;
                    }
                @endphp
                {{ $sum }}
            </td>
            <td>{{ $chemical->weight - $sum }}</td>
            <**td><input class="ts" id="remain_{{ $chemical->id }}" name="remain_{{ $chemical->id }}" type="number" max="{{ $chemical->weight - $sum }}">
            </td>**
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

```html
<script>
   $('.ts').TouchSpin({
      min: 0,
      max: $('.ts').attr("max"),
      step: 0.1,
      decimals: 2,
      boostat: 5,
      maxboostedstep: 10,
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.each()` method to loop over each instance of the `.ts` class selector and apply the TouchSpin based on the parameters of that particular input instance.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```js
<script>
    $('.ts').each(function() {
        $(this).TouchSpin({
            min: 0,
            max: $(this).attr("max"),
            step: 0.1,
            decimals: 2,
            boostat: 5,
            maxboostedstep: 10,
        });
    });
</script>
```